# Sending the data from Jira to Cosmos

Tags: jira

While sending the Historic data from Jira to Cosmos through Service Bus, Data is not pushing as we are getting below Errors

> Response from CommonLogic webapp : Error occured while sending message[adtjira001eu.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx] to topic[versions-xxxx] due to Unable to establish loopback connection

> 502 Bad Gateway: "The specified CGI application encountered an error, and the server terminated the process.

Please help me with  the above Issues

pushed the historic data of Jira by using the WebJobs, only some of the data is pushing but expected all data to be pushed to Cosmos